# Where do people use a state, city format instead of a city, state format for written locations?

Tags: expressions

I have received a number of emails in which the sender says they are from “state, city”. It strikes me as odd since the convention in most English-speaking countries is “city, state”. In what countries is the “state, city” format common?

Comment: When you say "state" are you using "state" to mean "Member state of the USA" or are you using it to mean "country". That distinction might make a difference to the answer you receive.

Comment: I agree that examples or more detail would be good. It could also be Indian state, which might open up other possible explanations.

Comment: @StuartF That's true, it could also be true of any confederation where the component parts are called "states" but that would have taken explanation and it was getting late when I typed that comment:-)